# build.ninja is not found when building Dart SDK

Tags: build, ninja, dart

I followed [the wiki](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Building#getting-the-source) accurately, but when I try to build, it fails:

```
$ gclient sync
... # A lot of syncing here
Running hooks: 100% (14/14), done.
$ cd sdk/
$ ./tools/build.py --mode release --arch x64 create_sdk
ninja -C out/ReleaseX64 create_sdk
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory
BUILD FAILED
$ ls out/ReleaseX64
args.gn build.ninja build.ninja.d dart-sdk obj toolchain.ninja
```

Answer (score 1):

At least on Windows this problem is caused because there was a problem (probably Visual Studio related) while running `build.py`. Because the script got interrupted, `build.ninja` doesn't get created. When running `build.py` again afterwards it doesn't attempt to create the build files (because the output folder is already created) and simply fails when not finding the `build.ninja`.

There is an [issue about this](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33796) on Github. For windows users I suggest to follow the following steps to install Visual Studio:

- Download Visual Studio 2019 Community (free) and install
- Open Visual Studio and in the menu go to Tools -> Get Tools and Features. Select "Desktop Development with C++" in the Workloads tab (default tab) and install.
- Go to Windows Apps & Features (where you uninstall programs), search for "Windows Software Development Kit" and click modify. Click on Change, select "Debugger" and proceed.

I also set the environment variable GYP_MSVS_OVERRIDE_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community but I think it's not necessary because the path is automatically detected by the scripts (if it is installed in the default path).

After that follow the other steps in the [wiki](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33796). Basically install the depot tools, do a "fetch dart" in a new "dart-sdk" folder, then run "gclient sync" from within the folder. Then from within "dart-sdk/sdk" run
`python ./tools/build.py --mode release --arch x64 create_sdk`

Answer (score 0):

For me removing the xcodebuild directory and resyncing worked (in the sdk directory)

```
rm -rf xcodebuild
gclient sync
```